# Pause the execution if constraint fails

Tags: javascript

My below function validates whether user entered url or not.

If rate = 0 then it should wait till user enter it. But in below case it shows the waring, but after that subsequent function calls get executed without waiting for user give the rate value.

How do I constraint it?

```
var rate = is_valid_rate();
function is_valid_rate()
        {
            var rate = $('#rateit99').rateit('value');
            if(rate == 0)
            {                   
                document.getElementById('rate_validate').style.color='#00BBFF';
                document.getElementById('rate_validate').style.display='block';
                //is_valid_rate();
            }
            else 
            {
                document.getElementById('rate_validate').style.display='none';              
                return rate;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't think you've shown all necessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you just need to return whether it was valid or not and the caller of this function needs to check the return value and act accordingly.

```
function is_valid_rate() {
    var rate = $('#rateit99').rateit('value');
    var rateObj = document.getElementById('rate_validate');
    if (rate == 0) {                   
          rateObj.style.color='#00BBFF';
          rateObj.style.display='block';
     } else {
          rateObj.style.display='none';              
     }
     return rate;
 }

var rate = is_valid_rate();
if (rate) {
    // put code here to execute when rate is valid
}
```

or since it looks like you're already using jQuery:

```
function is_valid_rate() {
    var rate = $('#rateit99').rateit('value');
    var rateObj = $('rate_validate').toggle(rate == 0);
    if (rate == 0) {                   
          rateObj.css('color', '#00BBFF')
    }
    return rate;
 }

var rate = is_valid_rate();
if (rate) {
    // put code here to execute when rate is valid
}
```